# How do you write a script to auto-fill other tables when someone submits a form?

Tags: sql, asp.net-core, stored-procedures, azure-sql-database

I am fairly new to SQL databases and stored procedures so I apologize in advance if this question is too general or dumb... I have made a web form using ASP.NET Core 2.2 MVC and it is connected to an Azure SQL database. The form takes in 3 inputs: `annual cost` [`decimal (19,4)`], `start month` [`date`], `duration` [`int`].

For example, if the user enters 120,000 for the `annual cost`, 09/01/2019 for `start month`, and 12 months for `duration`, then I would like the script to cut the annual cost by the duration and populate a table called *FY19* with 10,000 for the column *September*, 20,000 for the column *October*, 30,000 for the column *November*, 40,000 for the column *December*, **then go to another table** named *FY20* and continue filling it in until 120,000 for the column *August*.

My question is, should I write this script as a stored procedure? Or write it as a method in my project controller? If I write is as a stored procedure, is it possible to automate it so that every time new data gets inserted into the main table, the script fills in the *FYxx* tables?

Again, I apologize for making such a general question but I am kinda stuck in this problem. Any guidance would be appreciated and if anyone is willing to take an hour of their day to help me through skype I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: If you send your table structure and data like a sql table it will be easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TRIGGERS to automatically invoke SQL script.

You can do it manually in the controller too but I think it is more convenient to do with TRIGGERS.

Answer (score 0):

You can computed column on your 2nd table using the ID of your main table. Here's the link on how to add computed columns.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only 
answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thank you so much, I think this is what I was looking for!